# Cyrillic doesn't work in Django on Linux

Tags: django, encoding

I need cyrillic symbols in my website and it's work fine if it in template like: `Привет, мир!` or `{{ some_text }}` if i take it from MySQL database. But it doesnt work if i do something like this in **views.py:**

```
text = "Привет, мир!"
return render(request, 'index.html', {'text':text})
```

**template:**

```
{{ text }}
```

In windows it works OK, but in my production linux server it just outputs nothing. What is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Django doesn't have a problem outputting unicode characters,  are you sure you're view is calling that template? have you restarted the django instance on your server?

Comment: @Sayse if i change `text = "Привет, мир!"` to `text = "Hello, world!"` It works ok

Comment: Do you get any error in server logs? Unicode error or something like this. Another question - am I right that in the server you also tried to not fetching this text from database and to hardcode it?

Comment: Add `u` before str object -> `text = u"Привет, мир!"`

Comment: @madzohan There is an error 'utf8' codec can't decode byte invalid continuation byte...

Comment: @Paul there are no errors in log files. If i output cyrillic string just from database its work fine, If i output string from views.py - it is empty. If i try this - `text = u"Hello world!"` it works fine in windows, but in linux i have an error `'utf8' codec can't decode byte ...`

Comment: @worm2d hmm.. Did you set debug=true in the django settings on the server? If not, django could suppress errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i use `unicode("Привет, мир!", cp1251)` instead of `"Привет, мир!"` or `u"Привет, мир!"` and now it works.